# Where can I get Ubuntu for a smartphone?

Tags: android, phone

I have been to the Ubuntu website: http://www.ubuntu.com/phone , where it appears that you can get it for any smartphone, but where do I do so? I don't see a specific 'download' or 'installation process' link. The only thing I find is where I can fill out a form to contact them, but that is just for developers. I only want to install it on my personal phone, no developing.

Answer (score 0):

ROMs for specific devices, are pre-built and distributed ready to be flashed. They're distributed unofficially by those who compile and build it for their devices. You should search if anyone built Ubuntu for your phone in a mobile phone forum.

The most popular one is XDA at http://forum.xda-developers.com/